# dropping values with NaN while using pd.read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

read_csv for loading very different quite big data sets. Unfortunate they have some missing values and every time there is one missing the whole column is counted as string types. Is there a way to drop the rows of the values before? So I don't have drop the rows and cast every column manually?

Thanks for any Idea :)

Edit:

Sorry for the late edit, I had a stressful week. I figured out some part of the problem, but not sure how to fix this the best way.

My dataframe looks like:

[image: data frame with bad header]

I think the header is the issue bc I only get the problem with the pressure column. Has anyone an easy fix for that? If I skip the header I loose all column information.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Consider posting a few rows of CSV text directly here, redacted or mocked up as needed. Missing values should not automatically render string or object dtypes.

Comment: After reading the csv file, do you load it to a database? or where you do the manual cast? Add your code attempt and more details on steps you're taking.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had a stressful week. I posted my df where I could locate the problem. But not sure what's the best way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df.replace({np.nan: None})
# optional set the column type
df = df.astype({"a": int, "b": str})
```